Error connecting to the database: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when trying to connect to mysql container using node js
and I keep getting this error when trying to connect to my mysql image through in node.js project
Error connecting to the database: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 98b6c7aeb8af
I can access the container fine through the terminal using docker exec
No idea whats going wrong here.
docker run \
  --name mysql1 \
  --env-file .env \
  -e 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password' \
  -e 'MYSQL_DATABASE=login_proj_db' \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -d mysql:latest 

is the command I used to create my docker image and container
# SQL Server connection
SQL_USER=root@localhost
SQL_DATABASE=login_proj_db
SQL_SERVER=98b6c7aeb8af
# Set SQL_ENCRYPT=true if using Azure
SQL_ENCRYPT=false
SQL_PORT=3306

# MySQL root password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passowrd

this is my .env file
this is my test function for checking the connection
const sql = require('mysql2/promise');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

// capture the environment variables the application needs
const { PORT,
   HOST,
   HOST_URL,
   COOKIE_ENCRYPT_PWD,
   SQL_SERVER,
   SQL_DATABASE,
   SQL_USER,
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
   
} = process.env;

async function testDatabaseConnection(config) {
    console.log(process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)
    try {
        // Attempt to connect to the database
        console.log('attempting connection')
        const connection = await sql.createConnection(config);
        
        // If connection succeeds, log success message
        console.log('Connected to the database!');
        
        // Close the connection
        await connection.end();
        
        // Return true to indicate successful connection
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        // If an error occurs, log the error message
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error.message);
        
        // Return false to indicate connection failure
        return false;
    }
}

// Usage example
const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.SQL_SERVER,
    user: process.env.SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SQL_DATABASE,
    port: process.env.SQL_PORT
};

testDatabaseConnection(dbConfig);


SQL_SERVER=98b6c7aeb8af  shouldn't this be localhost? Docker container IDs are not network addresses

Or if the client code is itself running in a container, you need to docker network create a network, docker run --net both containers on that network, and then you can use the docker run --name of the database container as the host name, SQL_SERVER=mysql1.

@DavidMaze it's clearly not in this case but if it were, I'd recommend Docker Compose over doing it all manually

That would make sense.  Since Compose automatically sets up many of the key details you don't need to manually declare Compose container_name: or networks:.
